# Circuit to shutdown a ethernet cable

Tags: mosfet, ethernet, interface

I am a bit new in designing circuits. I am trying to make an interface to shutdown all the signals coming from an Ethernet cable. The design would look something like this:

[image]
Can this be done using mosfets? if so, would it cause packet drop? Any suggestions on how i could do this?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Easiest will be a bus switch. http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/scdb006a/scdb006a.pdf

Comment: It will be challenging to implement it without adverse effect on the signals, especially for Gigabit ethernet. Especially if it is in the middle of the cable. Putting it on the same PCB close to the PHY would be much better.

Comment: @mkeith Except Ethernet isn't a bus…

Comment: what about the signals that are being generated by any device on the right side of your diagram?

Comment: @duskwuff, you are just quibbling over terminology. They make switches that work with ethernet. The first time I used one was in 2000 on a single board computer with Gigabit Ethernet that could be routed to either of two jacks under BIOS control.

Comment: @duskwuff, something like the TI p/n TS3L501E. They don't call it a bus switch. You are right about that.

Comment: Thanks for your input everyone! sorry i should've been more clear with my issue. I don't plan to implement the circuit in the middle of the Ethernet  cable. I would essentially have one end of the cable going into the left end circuit and have another Ethernet cable connected on the left end of the circuit. @jsotola i hope this answers ur question :D

Comment: So basically, i would need the circuit to be able to turn off/on the data being transferred :)

Comment: @mkeith so does a bus switch prevent packet drop if the speed is 1 Gbps?

Comment: Might work. But it would work better if the switch was close to the source or destination. Google the IT part above. TS3L501E

Comment: @VarunMoturi, i was asking about the device on right side of your diagram .... ethernet at speeds of less than Gigabit uses only one twisted pair in each direction so you only need one DPST relay to turn off signal going from left to right (in your diagram) .... you did not say anything about signals that are generated on the right side of your diagram, so i asked, but you did not actually answer the question

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of this shutdown circuit? Safety in case of a electrical storm or just cutting off communications?                                 Quality Relays meant for small signals (gold plated contacts), would be the least problematic electrically and provide pretty good electrical isolation.

Comment: hey sara, so in this case, i would need to use 8 relays right? (relay for each signal)

Comment: Yes, you would. But it is the method least likely to cause any problems with data getting corrupted, one big reason, is that there would be zero power supply noise to contaminate the signal. It is the way I would go because of those reasons, and it is simple and reliable. Go with sealed relays, so the gold plated contacts could not be contaminated in any way by the atmosphere. These kind of signal relays would not draw much power either. It is the way I would go if I was building something that does what you need.